# Algorithm to find the coordinates of a point which is the reflection of a point about a line in 3D

Tags: algorithm, matlab, geometry

I am currently working on a project on Matlab and I need to find the coordinates of a point which is reflected about a line. I know how to do it in 2D but in 3D things are getting ugly.

So, we have a line which goes through two points A(x1,y1,z1) and B(x2,y2,z2). P1(x0,y0,z0) is reflected about that line and i need an algorithm to find the coordinates of reflection of P1.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about maths/geometry (try http://math.stackexchange.com).

Comment: I need the algorithm for this question. So, I better edit the content.

Comment: It sounds like you need the equation(s), which makes it a pure geometry issue.

Comment: Can you look at this question: [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3306838/algorithm-for-reflecting-a-point-across-a-line)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At first, find projection L of point P to line AB.

```
L = A + AB * ScalarProduct(AB, AP) / ScalarProduct(AB, AB)
```

Then calculate reflection

```
P' = P + 2*(L-P) = 2*L-P
```