# Processing - 3-way pong game

Tags: processing

My overall goal is to create a 3 way 'pong' game. A triangle border will be used with 3 paddles moving along each of the 3 sides. A ball will be bouncing within this triangle and the paddles will be used to try and stop the ball hitting each side of the triangle. To start off, I am trying to get a ball bouncing within the boundaries of a triangle. I currently just have a bouncing ball. Can anyone suggest how to go forward with this?

```java
float x = 100;
float y = 100;
float xspeed = 1;
float yspeed = 3.3;

void setup() {
  size(500,500);
}

void  draw() {
  background(255);

  fill(255,10);
  rect(0,0,width,height);

  x = x + xspeed;
  y = y + yspeed;

  if ((x > width) || (x < 0)) {
    xspeed = xspeed * -1;
  }

  if ((y > height) || (y < 0)) {
    yspeed = yspeed * -1;
  }

  fill(175);
  ellipse(x,y,16,16);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You're going to have to change your collision detection code so it detects when the circle collides with the triangle boundary instead of the edges of the screen.

Define your triangle as three line segments, then you can focus on detecting collision between the circle and each line segment. Google is your friend here, but [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1073336/circle-line-segment-collision-detection-algorithm) has a bunch of answers.

Then you'll probably want to reflect the point around the line so that the circle bounces at an angle based on the line segment. Again, google is your friend, but [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3306838/algorithm-for-reflecting-a-point-across-a-line) is another question with a bunch of answers.

I recommend splitting your problem up into smaller steps and focusing on one at a time. First get a program working that just checks whether a circle collides with a line segment: try hard-coded points at first, then maybe use the cursor position, then work your way up to a bouncing ball.